# Find ShareLaTeX default font type

Tags: fonts, sharelatex

I need to use in Word the same font type as in ShareLaTeX. ShareLaTeX explains the font types they use [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_typefaces), but I'm uncapable of finding which one is the default one. Is it Computer Modern Roman or Latin Modern Roman?

Is there any way to find it out?

I checked the pdf file produced by ShareLaTeX and the `file properties` of the pdf reports a dozen of different font types starting with "CM" (e.g. CMBX12, CMCSC10, CMMI6, etc.). Is it Computer Modern then?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: It is computer modern but don't use that, use latin modern which has compatible letter shapes and metrics but is available in an opentype font format and encodings that non-TeX programs will understand.

Comment: So computer modern is the one used by LaTeX but Latin Modern is the one that Word can digest?

Comment: yes you can use latin modern in latex as well `\usepackage{lmodern}`, and that's the default in xelatex or lualatex with fontspec, you can use the type1 cmr10 with Word but its encoding is somewhat eccentric so it may not give the results you expect. Most systems for example expect capital Gamma, if a font has it, to be at position U+0393, whereas cmr10 has it in position 0....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think the OP is asking which font is better. He wants to know which font ShareLaTeX uses by default, so that he can use that in Word. If ShareLaTeX uses Computer Modern by default, then that's the answer. Also, the problems you point out can be solved by using the unicode version of CM, cm-unicode.

Comment: @Sverre yes that is what I meant: (cm-unicode is an alternative to lmodern but same thing really in this context, neither is exactly cmr10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font used is [Computer Modern](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cm), but when using that font in MS Word, you should get the font in `.ttf` or `.otf` format with proper Unicode coding. There is a Unicode version of Computer Modern with those formats that you can download [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/files/cm-unicode/).

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the command `\familydefault` would return "cmr" so I understand that the font type used is Computer Modern Roman.